# Vue.js: Using mixin functions inside vue.router routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, mixins, vue-mixin

I want to dynamically set the title of the window for each route, so in each `routes: []` child object I have a `meta: { title: ... }` object.  For example:

```
routes: [
{
  path: 'profile/:id',
  name: 'Profile',
  component: Profile,
  meta: {
    title: function (to, cb) {
      const profileId = parseInt(to.params.id);
      // ... do stuff ...
    }
  }
}
]
```

I call this title function in an `afterEach` hook:

```
router.afterEach((to) => {
    document.title = 'My Site';
    if (to.meta && to.meta.title) {
        to.meta.title(router.app, to, (result) => { document.title += ' | ' + result; });
    }
});
```

In the `... do stuff ...` portion I want to call a method from my mixin `GetAndStore.js` called `loadProfile(profileId)`.  I added `GetAndStore` into the router's mixins, but `loadProfile` is not available (`this.loadProfile` is undefined).  I loaded `GetAndStore` globally and tried again with the same results.  I've tried every configuration I can think of for the past hour I've not found any way at all to access the methods from `GetAndStore` from within this setup.

Any ideas of what I'm missing or what I'd need to restructure in order to access mixin methods from within `routes->element->meta->title` ?

Comment: Can you show your mixin code? What dependencies does your `loadProfile` method have?

Comment: @Phil The `loadProfile` is super basic.  It makes an `axios` GET request and then resolves with the data.  It only depends on `axios`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that...

> Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for **Vue components**

Vue-router is not a component, nor do you have access to the component loaded for the route.

What I would suggest is making `loadProfile` a named export from your `GetAndStore` mixin. Assuming your mixin is exported like

```js
import axios from 'axios' // just an example

export default {
  methods: {
    loadProfile (profileId) {
      return axios.get(...)
    }
  }
}
```

you can move your function out of the default export and name it...

```js
export function loadProfile (profileId) {
  return axios.get(...)
}

export default {
  methods: {
    loadProfile
  }
}
```

then you can import just the `loadProfile` function in your route definitions...

```js
import { loadProfile } from 'GetAndStore'
```

---

Of course, you could also import your mixin as it is and just use

```js
import GetAndStore from 'GetAndStore'

// snip

GetAndStore.methods.loadProfile(to.params.id).then(...)
```

Comment: I'm marking this as "correct" because its the same conclusion that I came to, and the same implementation that I ended up using.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try do it on beforeRouteEnter inside Profile component. So there you can grab meta title and set title of page and there you will have access to mixin methods:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
  if (to.meta && to.meta.title) {
    to.meta.title(router.app, to, (result) => { document.title += ' | ' + result; });
  }
},
```

Docs: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards

Comment: I guess that's a possibility as the components will have access to mixins (whereas vue router apparently does not), but I like the idea of all route-oriented details being contained within the router file and not have some parts here, some over there, etc.